# Validating a group of controllers together using ONE validator in ASP. NET

Tags: asp.net

I have 3 DropDownLists, Day, Month, Year, so simply, date of birth.

I need to validate these 3 together, means, if I selected day = 2, and month = 3, but I didn't select a Year (default selected value = null), I need this validator to tell me that the DOB is not fully set.

How can I link these 3 DropDownLists together?

Comment: Why don't you use some good calender controls available freely http://jqueryui.com. Secondly why you cannot use simple javascript for this ?

Comment: It's a project, I'm forced to use ASP validators.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below